# ORA-20000: AOP Server can not be found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I installed AOP and have now a little problem. I get the error

ORA-20000: AOP Server can not be found. Check if it is running at http://api.apexofficeprint.com/

when trying to create a template or report.

Oracle Database 18 XE
Apex 20.1
Apex Office Print 20.2

Comment: Have you tried contacting AOP support? https://www.apexofficeprint.com/ords/uc/r/aop_portal/support

Comment: 3 emails + 1 bug feedback = 0 answers

Answer (score 2):

That's a general error you are receiving. This is more of a network issue than AOP.

The first step would be to check if you ACL has been set up properly. You could check this by executing the following through SQL Workshop -> SQL Commands:

```
select apex_web_service.make_rest_request('http://api.apexofficeprint.com/marco', 'GET') from dual;
```

if the ACL was configured properly you should get a "polo" string back.

If this does result in an error, you should be able to get the exact HTTP error by executing the following command:

```
select utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm from dual;
```

You should see something like this:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1577
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
```

The code to configure ACL can be found on [oracle documentation for 20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F)

I've pasted the code below to make it easier. You will need to connect to the database where Oracle Application Express is installed as SYS specifying the SYSDBA role.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
        host => 'api.apexofficeprint.com',
        ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
                           principal_name => 'APEX_200100',
                           principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

For completeness I am also hyperlinking it here for other versions of APEX.
: [APEX 5.0](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/listener.htm#HTMIG29160), [APEX 5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/enabling-network-services-in-Oracledb-11g-or-later.htm#HTMIG29160), [APEX 18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMIG/enabling-network-services-in-Oracle-db11g-or-later.htm#HTMIG29160), [APEX 18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F), [APEX 19.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F), [APEX 19.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-8D125731-989A-4A51-AFFE-00181729F87F)

Once this has been setup, you should be able to connect to api.apexofficeprint.com without issues. However please note that you are currently using http protocol which is unsecure and we recommend you to use https.

In order for you to use https, you will have to add the root certificate of AOP server. [This blog](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6121/index-en.html) capture the method in detail.

Furthermore if you have installed the AOP sample application, you can debug connection issues from connection test page (Debugging -> Test Connection). This page will detect the URL you have used for the plugin and allow you to check the connection. This detects ACL, wallet issues, certificate validation issue and if the server is running in the provided URL.

PS: Could it be that you used other email than support@apexofficeprint.com to contact us? I see that one of your email and the feedback were both answered within an hour.